# What is the purpose of customer_grid_flat table?

Tags: magento2, database, customer

can someone please tell me what is the purpose of Magento's customer_grid_flat table? What is it used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento2,  is used this flat table  for customer . It is basically  used for admin customer grid.

Magento2,  use  flat  tables  for  faster data fetch from  eav  models   like product,  category  and  customer. Use single tab  instead  of  multiple  tables.

Comment: When is the table populated and what module is used to do this?

Comment: https://jutesenthil.wordpress.com/2017/01/05/customer-grid-is-showing-empty-or-blank-in-magento-2/

Comment: @AmitBera flat option for customers can be enabled or disabled just like catalog and category?

Comment: No ,it doesn't have any setting  like.